# Script to execute a command for all files with ending .mp4 in a folder

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, ffmpeg

I'd like to execute the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video_file_input.mp4 video_file_output_2.mp4
```

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute the script inside the directory with the mp4 files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

for f in *.mp4; do
        ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}_2.${f##*.}"
done
```

The `"${f%.*}_2.${f##*.}"` part will insert the '_2' before the point.
More about the `set -euo pipefail` [here](https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/).

Comment: close >:-D the "in" in the name also needs to change to "out" :D

Comment: Possible, but why the "_2" when already has "output"? I think it is more like name example and not a real case with input and output.